# Deployment project in VisualStudio: Is the output in Debug or Releaase mode?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, setup-deployment

I have a solution in Visual studio containing a winform project(WinProj) and a deployment project for WinProj.

I added to the deployment project the primary output from WinProj. Does it be compiled in Debug or Release mode?

I am asking because in the WinProj code I have conditional precompiler statements

```
#if DEBUG
    throw;
#endif
```

will or not be considered this code in the setup project?

By default I don't switch the mode when building the setup project(remains in Debug). So should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend whether you compile your deployment and setup projects in Debug or Release modes.

Comment: what could be sense in a setup project compiled in debug mode? By default I don't switch the mode when building the setup project(remains in Debug). Perhaps I should do it, however...

Comment: I would strongly recommend you compiling in Release mode when shipping your application. For example if you have a continuous integration server performing builds it could be setup for Release mode, while on developer machines you could stay in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not sure if I understand the question.
Setup projects sould be created with release-built binaries. Inner IL is more efficient when compiled in release mode.
You may take a look with ildasm, difference in il code is huge.

Comment: "Setup projects should be created with release-built binaries." Yes, but apparently there is a "debug possibility" too(?!)... see Darin Dimitrov answer.